# Differences between 妊娠 and 受胎

Tags: words

Can you tell me what are the differences between:

<s>1)　**即時**　and　**即刻**?</s>

**妊娠**　and　**受胎**?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's appreciated if the questioner could provide their current understanding of the words and what they tried to research to this point. On a specific note, aren't the words in #1 identical?

Comment: Ok, sorry. As for the pair one, I meant 即時 and 即刻. To me, they seem to mean exactly the same (as you pointed out, I didn't even notice that I wrote one and the same word in my original post). However, in Japanese there are so many words that only SEEM to mean the same that I'm honestly completely lost.

Comment: For the first pair 即時 is adjective and 即刻 is adverb.

Comment: It'll be better if you separate them into 2 questions. Since there's an answer for the 2nd comparison, create a separate question for the 1st one. This helps the site catalogue questions neatly with useful question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that some English-Japanese dictionaries list 妊娠｛にんしん｝ as meaning "conception", but I do not agree with this. 妊娠 means pregnant (i.e. the state of carrying a fertilized egg / embryo in one's womb), where as 受胎｛じゅたい｝ means conception (i.e. the process of becoming pregnant).

If we check the Japanese explanations on kotobank.jp we have the following:

受胎

```
妊娠｛にんしん｝の成立｛せいりつ｝をいう。精子｛せいし｝が卵子｛らんし｝と出会｛であ｝って受精｛じゅせい｝が起｛おこ｝り，
受精卵｛じゅせいらん｝が卵管{らんかん}内｛ない｝を移動｛いどう｝して子宮腔｛しきゅうくう｝内に達｛たっ｝し，子宮｛しきゅう｝内膜｛ないまく｝に着床｛ちゃくしょう｝して妊娠｛にんしん｝するまでの一連｛いちれん｝の生理｛せいり｝現象｛げんしょう｝をさす。

The formation of a pregnancy. Sperm meets eggs such that fertilization occurs, whereafter 
the fertilized egg moves through the oviduct until it reaches the uterine cavity and gets 
implanted in the endometrium. This process leading to pregnancy is referred to as 受胎.
```

妊娠

```
受精卵{じゅせいらん｝が女性｛じょせい｝の体内｛たいない｝にある子宮｛しきゅう｝に着床｛ちゃくしょう｝、赤｛あか｝ちゃん（胎児｛たいじ｝）として成長｛せいちょう｝、赤｛あか｝ちゃんや胎盤｛たいばん｝が体外｛たいがい｝に出｛で｝るまでの
体｛からだ｝の“状態｛じょうたい｝”を妊娠｛にんしん｝といいます。

The state of a body, where a fertilized egg is implanted in the uterus of a female and 
develops into an infant (fetus), until the infant and the placenta goes out of the body, 
is referred to as 妊娠.
```

Comment: My theory about 妊娠 is that "conception" is really applicably only to 妊娠する form, but this nuance is missed in dictionaries...

Comment: Well, I would translate that to "become pregnant"